# Hosting two or more domain in windows VPS with one IP address?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, vps, web-hosting, bindings

I am very new for VPS. I have two domain www.onlinevisualkart.com and www.nripendraojha.com on godaddy, I have one VPS with Windows Server 2012 from third part company, I set ip of VPS (50.3.82.140) in domain www.onlinevisualkart.com then host my application in Default Website of IIS of my VPS. It working very fine. This is screen shot of www.onlinevisualkart.com
      [image: Image 1]

Now my problem is I want to host one more website (www.nripendraojha.com) in my VPS, I again set ip of VPS (50.3.82.140) in domain www.nripendraojha.com then host my application in my VPS by making new website in IIS. But when I try to open www.nripendraojha.com in browser it always open default website of my VPS that is www.onlinevisualkart.com. 
[image]

I think everyone get my point Means I want to host two domain in my VPS with single IP. Please any one tell me how I can resolve this problem? This is screen shot of IIS of my VPS.
[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 5):

According your screenshot, your site is `nripendraojha.com` and you are trying to access it using `www.nripendraojha.com`. You may need an additional *binding*:

1. Right click the site name.
2. "Edit Bindings"
3. "Add"
4. Enter the hostname `www.nripendraojha.com`.

Any hostname not having a matching binding will fall to the *Default Web Site*.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence which explains **why** it is a problem and not just how to solve it. (which is worth another +1).

Comment: ...Plus you shouldn't have an app on the default website, instead a maintenance page responding with a `503` response (makes maintenance easy)

Comment: Thanks for everyone for helping me, +1 for great suggestion for binding. But my problem was coming due to chrome browser cache. When I clear it, I able to access my both website. I find this solution when my one friend told me he is able to access my both website. Then I decide to clear my browser cache.